# RSelenium - For loop through multiple webpages, grab data and paste it into data.frame

Tags: r, web-scraping, rselenium

I'm trying to loop through a job listing website to grab their job listing and do text analysis. For this job I use RSelenium.
The code I am working on is as follows:

```
#### REMOTE.COM ####
remDR$navigate('https://remote.com/jobs/all?query=marketing&country=anywhere')
# click on the cookies policy
remDR$findElement(using = 'xpath', '//*[@id="ccc-notify-accept"]')$clickElement()
# print all job listings
num_links <- 20
for(i in 1:num_links){
  remDR$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                    paste('/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/article[',i,']', sep = ''))$clickElement()
  print(remDR$getCurrentUrl())
  remDR$goBack()
}
```

The problem is that when I get the loop started, two issues occur.

First, the `print(remDR$getCurrentUrl())` command returns the original url (https://remote.com/jobs/all?query=marketing&country=anywhere), not the page that was clicked on in the first part of the `for` loop. Second, when `remDR$goBack()` executes, it takes me back to the previous blank page, as if there was no link clicked on.

To summarize, I think the loop is running faster than Rselenium takes to find and click on the element.

##### EDIT

Solution was found thanks to a recommendation:

```
for(i in 1:5){
  remDR$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                    paste('/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/article[',i,']', sep = ''))$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2) # add time for page to load
  print(remDR$getCurrentUrl())
  remDR$navigate('https://remote.com/jobs/all?query=marketing&country=anywhere') # .$navigate() works better as it makes the page load and give you time
  Sys.sleep(2) # add time for page to load
}
```

The steps taken were to give chrome time to load the page `Sys.sleep(2)` and use `.$navigate()` instead of `goBack()`, reason is `.$navigate()` load content in browser. Important note, loop won't work without the final `Sys.sleep(2)` as you need the first page to completely load before the loop clicks on the second item.

Comment: Define a data frame outside loop, replace `print()` with `rbind()` to this dataframe. For delay use `Sys.sleep(5)` or whatever value it will be. Instead of `goBack()` script it to follow small right arrow on the bottom. Or add a number to `&page=2` URL part untill there is a result.

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko I don't follow the `goBack()`alternative. Can you expand more on that point?

Comment: @GrzegorzSapijaszko found a solution based on your recommendation!
for(i in 1:5){
  remDR$findElement(using = 'xpath', 
                    paste('/html/body/div[2]/main/div/div/div[3]/article[',i,']', sep = ''))$clickElement()
  Sys.sleep(2) # added time for page to load
  print(remDR$getCurrentUrl())
  remDR$navigate('https://remote.com/jobs/all?query=marketing&country=anywhere') # .$navigate() is the better solution
  Sys.sleep(2) #added time for page to load
}